# two model associations for a user ordered by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User who can post Topics and leave Comments. I have them default scoped to return by date.

I want to do something where I show all a users topics and comments together by date

Example:

- topic 10/4
- topic 10/2
- comment 10/3
- comment 10/1

would become:

- topic 10/4
- comment 10/3
- topic 10/2
- comment 10/1

What the best way to do this? aside from:

```
@variable = user.comments + user.topics
@variable.sort_by &:created_at    
@variable.reverse!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives I see here. One is to write pure SQL, which would look way more ugly than your 'three lines solution'. The other one would be to create a new AR model, like

```
class UserForumActivities < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name='user_forum_activities' # this is a name of psql view
end
```

The view could look like

```
class CreateSomeView < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
    execute %q{
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_forum_activities AS
    SELECT "comments.desired_fields", "topics.desired_fields"
    FROM "comments", "topics"
    INNER JOIN "users" ON "foreign_keys"
    WHERE "appriopriate conditions if needed"
    ORDER BY created_at;
    }
  end
end
```

Then in your controller, you could use it like:

```
@variable = UserForumActivities.scoped_to_user_with_id(user.id)
```

So, we get one line instead of three and you're letting your database to handle the logic for you (db is usually faster than Ruby). Hope that helps, also I am curious if someone shares even nicer solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved like activity stream. You can create one separated model named activity, and make relations to others entities. When user does something, like adding new comment or new topic, it should be also save in activity. Activity should have foreign keys to those models(topic, comment,...) in order to fetch them later. At the end, you just need to sort that activities and load you objects(topic, comment,..) and show.

There is a great tutorial how to do that, but it's unfortunately not free: http://railscasts.com/episodes/407-activity-feed-from-scratch

there is also one nice gem public_activity which can solve the problem. There is a tutorial how to do that (free one): http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity?view=asciicast